# Python 3.2 using a subprocess module

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.2 and Eclipse classic as an IDE. I m trying to add the users in rawinput to the existing group North_AMERICAS using a command as shown below. I tested the cmd and it does its job. Now for all the users in the rawinput, I want to add them to the group using python script. Below is my code and the error msg. Can you please let me know what am I missing? Thanks.

```
# coding=UTF-8
import subprocess
def AddUsers():
 rawinput = ('corp\\arrigh', 'corp\\banjar', 'corp\\bicknk', 'corp\\BINDEM')
for user in rawinput:
 rs = subprocess.call("c:/dicfg -remote admin:admin@myserver:2130 add user -user "+user+" -groups North_AMERICAS")
 print(user)
AddUsers()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 307, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/user21/Shworkspace/PYTHON TEST\PYTEST.py", line 5, in <module>
    for user in rawinput:
NameError: name 'rawinput' is not defined
ERROR: Module: PYTEST could not be imported (file: C:\Documents and Settings\user21\Shworkspace\PYTHON TEST\PYTEST.py).
```

Comment: It looks like you have indentation problems - if, indeed, you formatted your question correctly (`for` should be under the previous line's `rawinput`).

Comment: @malenkiy_scot- Thank you very much for your help. I m very new to python and eclipse IDE. Thanks for being so nice. :)

Comment: Ok, so it's not formatting problem. Then I'll post it as an 'official' answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, it's an indentation problem: `for` should be under the previous line's `rawinput`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was just the indentation prob. Thanks for helping me figure this out.